# Wamp server error. could not execute run action

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I am trying to start wamp serve which was totally running fine on my laptop two weeks ago, but now after two weeks I suddenly get this error:

could not execute menu item(internal error)[exception] could not execute run action: the directory name is invalid

When I click on wamp, then I go to apache, then I select service then test port 80 and this is what I see:

[image]

when I write localhost, it goes there but when I click on Localhost and phpMyAdmin, i get this error:
[image]

please tel me how I can fix this . thanks

Comment: You can try this `right click the wampmanager icon -> Refresh` possibly something got confused. Alternatively what has changed over the last 2 weeks on the Laptop.

Comment: @RiggsFolly no it didnt work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WAMP is trying to open your browser, but the directory in the settings is not correct. It could be that your browser is now located somewhere else. To fix this:

1. Edit the file wampmanager.conf inside your wamp direcotry.
2. Replace the full file path under the `[main]` section for the `navigator` parameter
3. Save the file
4. Right-click on the wamp icon and select refresh
5. Try it now

Good luck!

Comment: I am having the same error message - but my WAMP won't even start (no system tray icons when I run wampmanager.exe elevated). I was using Chrome so I changed wampmanager.conf's [main] navigator = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", but the error persists "Aestan Tray Menu has stopped working"  then "Exception Exception in module wampmanager.exe at 000F15A0 \n Could not execute run action: \n The directory name is invalid". WIll keep trying.

Comment: I had this same error message when trying to edit configurations. Solution is the same, only the parameter is "editor". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The paths are incorrect in multiple ini files and the wampmanager conf file.  Here are the ones I changed since my installed moved from g drive to e drive.  I had to change all instances of g:/ to e:/ as well as my chrome.exe location

wampmanager.conf:
in the [main] section update the path of chrome.exe or ensure it is correct.

wampmanager.ini:
change all instances of g:/ to e:/ (or whatever your install drive letter is)

php.ini (under /wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/)
again, change all instances of g:/ to e:/ (change to your install letter)

Wampmanager started correctly once these changes were made.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and to get my WAMP server working again on my laptop I ran the executables for Apache and MySql independant of the WAMP system tray icon.

In Windows Explorer, I ran (elevated):

{wamp folder in my case C:\wamp}bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\ApacheManager.exe

This put the apache manager system tray icon in.
then I used the apache system tray icon to start apache server
Then I ran (elevated):
{C:\wamp}bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysqld.exe

This allowed me to use localhost\phpmyadmin, which to me demonstrates the php, mysql and apache are all working.

My web app was also back and running.

The age of my MySql version and apache version show how long this had been stable for.

I initially thought the problem may have been caused by a google chrome upgrade which included the notifications icon in the system tray, as the chrome upgrade was the only thing I recall changing. I unistalled chrome but this did not fix it  - although this does not rule out Chrom Notifications being what broke it!

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an oversight on the WAMPSERVER developers.  For some reason it does not translate the file path syntax from Linux to Windows, resulting in the following error message:

**Aestan Tray Menu:**  Could not execute menu item (internal error) 
[Exception] Could not execute run action: The directory name is invalid

To fix this, edit wampmanager.conf and replace the forward slashes in the file path with backslashes.

**EXAMPLE:**

Incorrect

```
editor ="C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"
```

Correct

```
editor ="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
```

Save the file, then right click the tray icon and select "Refresh".  You should now be able to edit your files with your selected editor without issue :)

Answer (score 0):

i have met this problem and fixed by editing 4 files 
- wampmanager.conf in root
- wampmanager.ini in root
- php.ini in (wamp64/bin/php/php5.5.12)
- httpd.conf in (wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf)

Answer (score 0):

1)Edit the file wampmanager.conf

2)Replace the full file path under the [main] section for the navigator parameter

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

3)Save the file

4)Right-click on the wamp icon and select refresh