# Wamp server is online, but menu is not working

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, joomla3.0

I installed Wampserver 3 64-bit on Windows Server 2012R2.
Wampserver is online (green), SQLP and Apache are both working good, but when click on the menu - `PHP > PHP Error log` and `Apache > Apache Error Log` or some other menu I get the message below:

"Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not execute run action. The system cannot find the file specific"

Can anyone help me?

Thx

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382575/wamp-server-error-could-not-execute-run-action

Comment: Which version of Joomla! are you using?, at this moment the last version available  is **J3.5.1**.

Comment: last version joomla 3.5.1