# I changed the name of my wamp folder - what happened to my dbs?

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

In order to try another version of my WAMP server, I changed it's folders name from /wamp64/ to /wamp64-old/ and downloaded another WAMP, tried to install it, and well... my localchost/phpmyadmin was... empty. Can I get it back?!

This morning, I had some issues installing a project on my computer. I think it was the version of my PHP. So I decided to load another version on my WAMP server. Then, it was a mess. Nothing was working, I changed a bunch of files, and I was lost.

So, like I said, I renamed my folder, try another version of WAMP, from a brand new download on the website, and then, I just clicked: what was going to happen to my databases?! I checked and... everything is gone.

I tried renaming my first folder and I can get my WAMP server to start, I get a Aestan Tray Menu error saying that it could not execute run action, sooooo nothing is working. At all.

So, first problem: is there a way to get back my databases!?!?!?!

Second problem: How do I get my old lovely WAMP to work again? I backed up my www folder...

Comment: Well a backup for your databases would be nice. That said WAMP stores databases in the WAMP directory. Path looks something like this :`\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-version\data`. You might be able to backup that folder, make a clean install of WAMP, and replace the MySQL data folder.

Comment: aaaaaannnnnd you are officially my new favorite person in the world. backup done. Can I put in the trash bin all the files, program, everything (that is not my data backup or my www backup ? without losing anything? I think something interfere with a clean installation of wamp.

Comment: I'd try fixing WAMP without deleting anything. Since you seem to have changed WAMP versions my guess is some configuration paths are not correct anymore and result in the Aestan Tray Error => https://stackoverflow.com/a/34661253/8474896.